# Suspected DNS issue on Windows 2000 server

Tags: windows-networking

I'm hosting a (kind of) intranet site on a Windows 2000 server. The problem is that when I type the FQDN of the site (fireseed5060.fs5000.net) from the server itself, I can access the site just fine. However, on other devices in the LAN, I can only access the site by entering the local IP address of the server. This implies that there is a DNS configuration issue on the server. Can you please provide me with possible solutions to this problem along with detailed steps on how to apply these solutions? Thanks in advance.

NSLOOKUP output
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

Comment: Can you please provide detailed information about how you created the fs5000.net domain? As it doesn't seem to actually _exist_ on the public DNS, what steps have you taken so far to let other hosts resolve it?

Comment: I created a forward lookup zone named fs5000.net and a reverse lookup zone 192.168.1... It's just an intranet/LAN site, so there's really no need to register it publicly. Only the server machine seems to be resolving. No other device on the LAN will resolve.

Comment: What DNS server are your client computers using? Can you add the output of `nslookup fireseed5060.fs5000.net` and `nslookup -q=soa fs5000.net` _from a client machine_ into the main post?

Comment: I edited the main post to include the nslookup command output.

Comment: If that's the nslookup result from your client, you are almost to an answer. Your client is asking a public DNS server (1.1.1.1) for resolution of a domain (fs5000.net) that the DNS server is unaware of. To get this to work, you either need to register fs5000.net and establish a public-facing DNS environment, or you need to change your clients to use an internal DNS server that will answer DNS queries for fs5000.net.

Comment: Option 2 is the easiest and cheapest.